# How to have Node.js microservice's client published as an independant package from the same repo?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, microservices

I'm currently working on a web application and I've decided to use the client <-> api <-> [microservices] pattern.

I'm challenging myself by developing my microservices in Clean Architecture with node.js using Typescript.

I've already done the exact same thing in Go but for some reasons here I would like to use node.js.

The development of the microservice itself is not an issue at all, it's working well and I'm pretty happy with what I've done considering I'm not used to develop in Typescript at all.

Anyway, my problem here is:
in Go, I was able to build the microservice's client and publish it in the same time and most importantly from the same repo as the microservice itself. It's pretty handy because the client can then encapsulate all the custom types and data models for example.

Here I would like to do the same: I have a main repo with

```
> dist //where JS files will be generated of course
> src //where you can find my TS files
  > controllers
  > factories
  > models
    > objects
      - InputObject.ts
  > repositories
  > routes
  > services
  > use_cases
  - index.ts
```

I would like to put my client library in a subfolder of this main repo.

I could use git submodules, or npm target, but the question is, let's say my tree is like that:

```
> dist
> client
  > src
    - index.ts
  > dist
    - package.json
> src
  //all the same as above
```

How is it possible from `client/src/index.ts` to use types from `src/models/*` and to have them
working when I `npm publish`? Is that even possible?

Thanks a lot for your attention and participation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a great package that allows me to do that: Lerna (https://github.com/lerna/lerna)